# How should I manage multithreaded concurrent access to an ArrayDeque?

Tags: java, concurrency, jlist, deque

My Swing GUI displays a JList of items that are being sequentially removed by a background thread.

Behind the JList is an `ArrayDeque<Card>`, myHopper, implementing `myHopper.getSize()` and `myHopper.getElementAt()`, as per the contract of an AbstractListModel.

The background thread removes items using `myHopper.poll()`.

Not surprisingly, I'm getting AWT array index out of bounds exceptions currently.

What should I be doing to properly synchronize access to myList between the EDT thread and my background thread?  I have seen references to `Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList)` but I don't think that fits my ArrayDeque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to my question appears to be "You can't: you must never attempt to access a Swing component [and that includes its model] from any thread other than the EDT."

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036509/how-do-i-simulate-a-buffered-peripheral-device-with-swingworker/7055439#7055439) shows how I eventually solved the problem.  A worker thread needs to pull an item from a JList's model, and does so using `invokeAndWait()` to schedule that work *on the EDT*, and then waits until that task is done, and then continues.

Using the synchronized LinkedBlockingDeque didn't work, and I suspect that it's because the EDT makes a nonatomic *series* of calls to the Deque interface when updating the GUI component.  Any change to the model *between* calls, by another thread, could destroy any assumptions of stability that the EDT is making.

(Perhaps that's what's being hinted at by the persistent "**Warning:** Swing is not thread safe" that appears throughout the Swing documentation.)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried just using a [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) instead of the ArrayDeque?

Comment: I was able to substitute it without any complaint from the compiler, and I suspect a linked list might be a better implementation for a Deque than an Array; however, I'm still getting AWT array index out of bounds exceptions.  I did find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440360/jlist-throws-arrayindexoutofboundsexceptions-randomly/3440436#3440436 which indicates that one should _never_ modify the model on any thread other than EDT.  Kind of makes sense, although I can't quite say why.  Back to the drawing board....

Answer (score 1):

The following code works well for me, and might give you some ideas.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;

public class JListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyListModel model = new MyListModel();

        // set up a background task to periodically purge items from the list
        java.util.Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String item = model.poll();
                if (item != null) {
                    System.out.println("Removed " + item + " from list");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nothing to remove off list, click 'Add Item' button to add more");
                }
            }
        }, 1000, 2000);

        JList list = new JList(model);

        // Add a button to add new items to the list
        JButton button = new JButton("Add Item");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.offer(new Date().toString());
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Demo");
        frame.add(list);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyListModel extends DefaultListModel {
        private final ArrayDeque<String> dq = new ArrayDeque<String>();

        public synchronized String poll() {
            String head = dq.poll();
            if (head != null) {
                removeElementAt(0);
            }
            return head;
        }

        public synchronized void offer(String item) {
            dq.offer(item);
            insertElementAt(item, getSize());
            System.out.println("Added " + item + " to list");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute your operations using SwingWorker instead.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that will help.  As I am coming to understand it, if _any_ thread other than the EDT modifies the list model (even one that's got concurrency protection), it runs the risk of doing so during a GUI redraw by the EDT.  If the redraw requires more than a single access to the list model, then a rogue modification by another thread will probably destroy any assumptions of stability made by the GUI redraw routine.  This is just a guess; I wonder if anyone else can shed light...